# Block being pulled from rest on a frictional surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

An initially stationary block of mass $m$ has a force, $F = 0.500mg$, applied to it at an upward angle $θ = 20˚$ above the horizontal. What is the acceleration of the block if the frictional coefficients are $\mu_s = 0.600$ and $\mu_k = 0.500$?

I set up the equation as such: $F\cosθ - F_n \mu_k = ma$

Since $F_n = mg - F\sinθ$, the equation becomes:

$F\cosθ - (mg - F\sinθ) \mu_k = ma$.

This is easy enough to solve, and I am getting an answer of $0.54ms^{-2}$ but this does not agree with some other answers online. Other answers seem to be incorporating the coefficient of static friction, but I cannot figure out why this would be relevant if the block is accelerating and moving. Does the fact that it is initially at rest have anything to do with it?
Other sources are saying that the correct formula is $(mg - F\sinθ)u_k + F\cosθ - mgu_s = m * a$ but I can't understand why the static friction coefficient comes into play.
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: What you posted seems correct. Maybe you made a mistake elsewere.

Comment: Upward angle $\theta$ with what? horizontal? vertical? some other reference?

Comment: upward angle θ above horizontal

Comment: Static friction would be used to determine the minimum force needed to make the block move.  After that, kinetic friction would come into play.  Did a previous part of the problem ask for the minimum force, then assume that force was maintained?

Comment: How are you getting any numerical answer if you don't know $F$?

Comment: Sorry, $F=0.500mg$

Comment: No @BillN There was no previous part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've computed the acceleration of the block *once it is moving*. However, if the block starts stopped there is a minimum force needed to get it started that is larger than the force needed to maintain it's motion.

That minimum force to start the motion is computed using the maximum force of static friction and the assumption of equilibrium. The working look very much like what you have done, but set $a$ to zero and use the coefficient of static friction.

Take particular note that there is a range of forces that results in positive acceleration once the block is in motion but is not sufficient to get the block started in the first place.

Comment: I understand that you must overcome the max force of static friction to get it moving, but once it is moving wouldn't only the kinetic frictional force apply to it? Thus when you're calculating the acceleration, it must be moving so only the kinetic frictional force acts on it? What does the FBD look like under your description? How do both the kinetic and static frictional forces act on it?

Comment: Yes, once it is moving you use the kinetic value. No, you never use both. The reason you see people using the kinetic value is either that they are answering a different question or that they are confused.

Comment: @BrooksRalph There are two separate cases, you correctly solved for the case where the block is sliding. Now to find out if the block starts sliding you could calculate the acceleration with the static fiction just like you did for the kinetic friction. If your acceleration is negative then you wouldn't start sliding, but if it's positive then you would. In no case should you be using both the static and kinetic coefficients of friction (unless your studying the dynamics of stick-slip or other more advanced topics)